# How to override .phtml file in module?

Tags: module, magento2.3, phtml, plugin, third-party-plugin

I am trying to change **sign in or create an account** message which is called by block named `product.review.form` in  **catalog_product_view.xml**.

> /vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

[image]

The template used is **form.phtml** which is set in `Magento\Review\Block\Form.php`

[image]

I want to override this part of code in

> /vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/form.phtml

```
<?php else : ?>
    <div class="message info notlogged" id="review-form">
        <div>
            <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Only registered users can write reviews. Please <a href="%2">Sign in</a> or <a href="%1">create an account</a>', $block->getLoginLink(), $block->getRegisterUrl()), ['a']) ?>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endif ?>
```

**Question** : How can i override the sentence in that particular `<div>`?

**Note** : I tried to use plug-in but _construct() is protected and using preference is not suitable for my requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be override by adding the content / message in the en_US.csv file in the your custom theme.

For reference check the row 120 in `sitename/vendor/magento/module-review/i18n/en_US.csv`.